# Mocking any value as input parameter with ZIO Test

Tags: scala, mocking, zio, zio-test

I mock the following function:

```
def deploy(deployRequest: DeployRequest, mergeResults: Seq[MergeResult]): Task[Deployment]
```

For the result I don't care for the inputs. So my question, is there a Way to achieve this with `zio.test.mock`.

Something like:

```
ProcessEngineMock.Deploy(any, any) returns value(deployment)
```

(`deployment` is the output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Assertion.anything` should do the work

Comment: Thanks -  that is what I was looking for. However `Deploy(Assertion.anything) returns value(deployment)` gives me `unsatisfied expectations...Deploy with arguments anything()` How is this possible? `anything` would suggest there are no expectations.